# Can I run a job under another job's steps in CircleCI 2.0?

Tags: circleci, circleci-2.0, circleci-workflows

Is it possible to have another job run in the context of another job? I have some jobs that have some steps in common, and I don't want to repeat these steps in the different jobs.

```
push-production-image:
docker:
  - image: google/cloud-sdk:latest

working_directory: ~/app

steps:
  - setup-gcp-docker
  - run: docker push [image]
```

Answer (score 5):

No you cannot however YAML itself has a way to solve this problem with what is called YAML Anchors and Aliases.

Here's a blog post I wrote on how to do specifically this: https://circleci.com/blog/circleci-hacks-reuse-yaml-in-your-circleci-config-with-yaml/

Comment: My only problem is the steps that are run usually lose context outside the anchor e.g. if i install a binary in the anchor, I don't have access to the binary outside the anchor and alias

Comment: You can 1) Do the installation in the anchor, 2) Install the binary in a Docker image, or 3) Persist the binary in workspaces.

Comment: @ FelicianoTech please how do I persist an installed and already configured gcloud sdk?

Comment: You can use Workspaces to persist the binary and any config files where gcloud stores data: https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/workflows/#using-workspaces-to-share-data-among-jobs